# Aging away of flags

Tags: support, flags

Is the SO team / community doing anything about aging away of flags?

[image]
As above, in my case about 1/3 of flags have aged away (probably because they were not reviewed). I am sure there are several others with same issue.

I am taking lot of efforts to go through the queue. If flags are expiring instead of being approved or rejected, It is counter-productive and It's neither helping the OP, reviewers, nor the community as a whole.

Is the issue that there are not enough reviewers to approve/dis-approve flags? Or do we need to increase the duration of flag expiry? Perhaps lowering points required to review a flag may help or extending flag expiry period (assuming those are the reasons).

Does anyone from the SO team / community has any update on this?

** UPDATE **
I see that this question is voted as duplicate and being closed down.
However, Apart from question, I have also offered some possible solution that can be given some thought.

Comment: What types of flags? Flags to close I assume?

Comment: Close flags are going to age away.  It is just a fact of life right now on SO.  There is too much to close and not enough people hitting the queues and closing the stuff that needs to be closed.  This is even more pronounced in low traffic tags.

Comment: Would having that flag be listed as pending until the end of time actually be better than just seeing it marked as having aged away?  Would that make you feel better, even if you knew it would never be looked at by anyone, ever?

Comment: Please post suggestions as separate properly tagged post(s)... Make sure that was not discussed first - close votes limits/queues/flagging is almost daily topic on META, so take your time to scan through existing discussions before asking.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is your problem:

> [image: 9.1k Questions: Close Votes]

There simply aren't enough people working the queue, and flags are given a low priority in the sort order.

---

There are two things you can do:

- Earn that rep! At 3k you will be able to work the CV queue and help reduce its size. Close votes take the place of close flags, too.
- Review your flags. Sometimes, a question is poorly/obscurely tagged, and doesn't reach anyone in the queue. In many cases, this also means that nobody voted, answered, or even commented on it. Consider down voting (if you haven't already) to (possibly) make the question eligible for [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).